# QFileDialog::getOpenFileName poor performance and user experience

Tags: c++, qt, c++17

I want to let my users select an existing file from the filesystem. Looks like Qt's solution is `QFileDialog`. I looked up the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName) and came up with something like this:

```
void MainWindow::openFileDialog()
{
  const QString& inifilePath =
      QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                                   tr("Select Ini file"),
                                   QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DesktopLocation),
                                   tr("Ini files (*.ini)"));
  qDebug() << inifilePath;
}
```

`MainWindow` is my main window class. The problem is that file dialog window opens unacceptably slowly. After that it is still glitchy. If you right-click on something on the side bar, it again takes forever to show the rightclick options and you get a runtime warning-like output:

```
***********Create CommApi2Trayhelper************
***********Destruct CommApi2TrayHelper************
**********CommApi2TrayHelper::UnInitCheck*************
```

When the user selects some file and clicks OK program gives another runtime warning:

```
shell\comdlg32\fileopensave.cpp(14403)\comdlg32.dll!00007FFD757795AE: (caller: 00007FFD757A8291) ReturnHr(1) tid(1d9c) 80004005 Unspecified error    CallContext:[\PickerModalLoop]
```

All these lead me to believe that I am doing something wrong, even though I am doing exactly what the examples in the docs are doing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I noticed very slow reactions of file dialogs (opened via `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName()`) when it tried to resolve non-available network drives. Disconnecting these network drives fixed this. So, this wasn't something I could actually blame Qt for. Btw. the Windows file explorer showed similar behavior in this situation. Shell Explorer plug-ins are another source of problems. In this case, the `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName()` even crashed. Disabling the plug-ins helped.

Comment: @Scheff I have no network drives at all and the file dialog for every other application works fine. I tried this function on another machine too and observed the same behavior. I am wondering if using Win32 api for this function could fix my problems. That would hurt portability though

Comment: The `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName()` uses native file dialogs be default. I believe this can be changed by flags. If you instance `QFileDialog` (instead of using the `static` member functions) it's non-native definitely. May be, something you could try...

Comment: Concerning flags: Have a look at [QFileDialog::Option](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#Option-enum) i.e. `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog`.

Comment: @Scheff I used `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog` flag and it does solve the problems, at the cost of being uglier. I guess I am going to stick to this nonnative one for the time being.

Comment: _at the cost of being uglier_ :-) I fully agree. You could consider to make this an option of your application (a checkbox in app. settings or something similar). I like the native file dialogs because they support drag&drop, file renaming, file deleting, etc. But they are also a source of additional problems sometimes (as described above).